# What is the lowest SQL Server 2005 edition to support SSIS?

Tags: sql-server-2005

What is the lowest SQL Server 2005 edition to support SSIS?

Answer (score 2):

The standard edition for the basic transforms.

The advance edition for the advanced transforms.

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/compare-features.aspx#integration